# Is there a way to use python's argparse without explicitly listing what arguments are being passed in with add_argument?

Tags: python, argparse

I'm setting up a render farm that will be handling all sorts of jobs, with different arguments passed via command line. I'd rather not have to update the following *params* list every time I add a new command line parameter/kwarg. Is there a way to access the arguments being passed in with argparse without explicitly using add_argument for each kwarg?

```
params = ['type', 'action', 'renderDir', 'destination', 'computer', 'user', 'msg', 'data1']
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
for p in params:
    parser.add_argument(f'-{p}', f'--{p}')
args = parser.parse_args()
```

For example, if I use command line to pass in *-myParameter*, I'd rather not have to add *'myParameter'* to the *params* list in order to access *args.myParameter*. I'd also like to be able to access the keys as I iterate through *args*, so I have access both to the string *'myParameter'* and to the value of *args.myParameter*.

Comment: Without writing your own parser? probably not.

Comment: And recent https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54076485/argumentparser-parsing-optional-arguments-not-defined-in-parser (with lots of duplicates).

Comment: `vars(args)` is a dictionary, giving access to the `attributes` as `keys`.

Comment: You could scan `sys.argv` for `'-{}` and '--{}` strings, and add those to your `params` list.

Comment: @hpaulj yup. I discovered sys.argv a couple hours ago. exactly what I needed. thanks.