# How to parse a varying number of named arguments with argparse?

Tags: python, python-3.x, argparse

Parsing an unknown number of positional arguments is possible by setting `nargs` to `*`.

Is there any way to parse an unknown number of named arguments with argparse?

For example:

```
>>> import argparse
>>> parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
>>> parser.add_argument("optionals", nargs="**")
>>> parser.parse_args(['--foo', 'FOO', '--bar', 'BAR'])
Namespace(optionals={'foo': 'FOO', 'bar': 'BAR'})
```

I can try and parse the resulting list that comes out of `nargs='*'` but that will prove to be inefficient with lots of edge-cases.

Comment: There is `parser.parse_known_args` which will give you a list of all args that have not been parsed as well (but it does not e.g. remove the `"--"`).

Comment: It's not clear what you are looking for.  Could you please provide some specific examples that show inputs (command lines) and how you want to see the results.

Comment: Nope, `argparse` doesn't have a tool to do this for you.  If you want to accept arbitrary pairs of flag and value do your own processing (eg. from `sys.argv`).

Comment: One could do this by parsing the arguments extracting all the options and then building a parser with all the options passed in and the using that parser. It is not a good idea but I had to at least say it was possible.

Comment: Lots of duplicates listed in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54076485/argumentparser-parsing-optional-arguments-not-defined-in-parser?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: @hpaulj Thank you for that. Most of the duplicates listed there were not so relevant to the main duplicate but the fourth one stating "Parse non-pre-defined argument" is quite close. You should post the fact that `argparse` doesn't have the means of doing it as an answer :-)